# Make a DB2 Schema public so that all tables are readable to PUBLIC

Tags: sql, db2

I have a shared schema that any user (PUBLIC) should be able to read. However, I can only find a way to set each table PUBLIC. Is there a way to set the schema to have all of their tables SELECT PUBLIC?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43795/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-all-tables-in-a-schema-to-a-user-in-ibm-db2

Comment: I remember seeing this. I guess there isn't a way of setting it on the schema level. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this in DB2 for Linux, Unix and Windows.
The only thing you can do is running some code automatically (using DB2 ATS or other schedulers), which would grant missing grants on tables of the schema to PUBLIC.